# Windows: Maximize Around / Treat my window like the task bar?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

We're working on a "dashboard" app that basically "always on top" and hangs out on the left side of the screen in annoying sort of way. (This is an internal corporate app and not something the world will be subjected to and then roundly reject)

My question: Is there some sort of way to make other application windows treat my application window like the task bar? IE when someone maximizes the application it won't maximize behind my application?

We can already keep it on top but I think it's going to be super annoying if we cut off 1/8 of their app windows when they maximize.

We're currently writing this in C++/Qt and targeting Win7 / Win8.

Thanks!

Comment: two perhaps more practical options. (1) make it system tray thing instead of hanging out permanently on the desktop. (2) let it support mouse-over transparency with click-through like ClockX (of course then it also needs some interaction thing, like, system tray).

Comment: Try to read qwindowsysteminterface.cpp in source codes of Qt. In this file you can find processing of modification of availableGeometry. I hope somewhere in this file you can find way to influence on availableGeometry.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an "[app bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". I've done this in Qt before, but don't have time to provide a full answer here.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks, I have updated my answer with your information :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** The best way to do this is to use the AppBar API as in the comment of @andrewMedico. This will ensure the system is aware of the appbar and will ensure that you are docked to the screen correctly and do not overlap the taskbar or other appbars.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In XP what you are looking for is called a "Desk Band".

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx

Unfortunately this is deprecated in windows 7. I don't know if it works or not.

Alternatively, in Vista and WIndows 7 you can use a Gadget on the gadget bar.

The underlying way this works is by calls to `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA)`. This tells the system where the "maximise space" is. If you are not using the recommended AppBar API, you will need to occasionally check (or get notifications) when any other program changes the work area so you can ensure you are accommodated.