# Set window bounds

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry

I have searched for a while and cannot seem to find the answer.

I have made my own taskbar (replaced the shell), and when I maximize a window (lets say notepad) it will draw to the bottom of the screen and not to the top limit of my taskbar. I know there is a registry setting to adjust this but not sure where it is located.

Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 10

Comment: [**First result**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9233a75c-761e-484b-8d11-4ab40dcce5ea/taskbar-height-registry-key-or-gpo?forum=w7itprogeneral) googling _"Windows taskbar height registry"_. Also voting to close as off-topic because this isn't really about programming, it should've been asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows: Maximize Around / Treat my window like the task bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016897/windows-maximize-around-treat-my-window-like-the-task-bar)